# Using child table fetch the values from the parent table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables which are not connected and I have created the third table there I have created two fields which will be the foeign from the above two tables

Table 1:
studentid studentname studentemail

Table 2:
subjectid subjects

Table 3:
studentid subjectid

Table 1 consists of studentid which is the primary key and student name and student email

Table 2 consists of subject id and subject names.Subject id is the primary key

The purpose of table 3 is one student can take one or more subjects in each year.So subjectid and studentid are foreign key of table1 and table2.

What is the expected result is ,based on the subjectid the students name should get displayed

For example if I give subject id is 2,I need the students list who are all taken that subject

Comment: [SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: I have a question ,How do I connect the table only with foreign keys ?How the joins work here?I am new to the database

Comment: See example with 3 tables here (last example): https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join

Comment: I finally found the answer by myself."select student_name from table1 join table3 on table1.student_id=table3.student_id where table3.subject_id=1;"

Comment: Okay. But choose better names for the tables like `student`, `subject` and `student_subject`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer by myself.

```
select
    student_name
from
    table1
    join table3
        on table1.student_id=table3.student_id
where
    table3.subject_id=1;
```